# ABCL - error trying to add component to JPanel - add not found

Tags: java, swing, common-lisp, abcl

I am trying to build a Java GUI using ABCL. However, it throws an error.

```
#<THREAD "interpreter" {67D71B82}>: Debugger invoked on condition of type JAVA-EXCEPTION
  Java exception 'java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: No applicable method named add found in javax.swing.JPanel'.
Restarts:
  0: ABORT     Return to debug level 1.
  1: TOP-LEVEL Return to top level.
```

My code is as follows:

```
(defconstant +jframe+ "javax.swing.JFrame")
(defconstant +jpanel+ "javax.swing.JPanel")
(defconstant +button+ "javax.swing.JButton")

(defconstant +flowLayout+ "java.awt.FlowLayout")
(defconstant +dimension+ "java.awt.Dimension")

(defun make-frame (name width height) 
   (let ((this (jnew +jframe+ name))
        (dims (jnew +dimension+ width height)))

        (jcall "setPreferredSize" this dims)
        this))

(defun make-panel ()
   (let ((this (jnew +jpanel+)))
       this))

(defun make-button (name)
    (let ((this (jnew +button+ name))
        this)))

(defun main ()
   (let ((frame (make-frame 
                   "This is my frame"
                   400 300))
         (panel (make-panel))
         (button1 (make-button
                   "Press me"))
         )

    (jcall "add" frame panel)  
    (jcall "add" panel button1 (jfield +flowLayout+ "LEFT"))   

    (jcall "pack" frame)
    (jcall "setVisible" frame t)

))
```

The error is on line `(jcall "add" panel button1 (jfield +flowLayout+ "LEFT"))`. Commenting this out leads to a working application.

Answer (score 2):

According to [1] you need to use `jclass` to get the java class objects for each of the parameters, and then `jmethod` to find the right overload, and then finally you can call `jcall`

1: https://armedbear.common-lisp.dev/doc/abcl-user.html

Comment: See also the JSS contrib syntax: https://abcl.org/trac/browser/trunk/abcl/contrib/jss/README.markdown